# Are two different modules created to store the information of the __name__ variable?

Tags: python, import, module

```
#foo.py
import bar
print(__name__)
```

```
#bar.py
import foo
print(__name__)
```

When `foo.py` was run, the output was as follows:

```
bar
foo 
__main__
```

`print(__name__)` in `foo.py` is executed twice and produces two different outputs. So are two different modules of `foo.py` created to store the information of the `__name__` variable, which is different in both cases?

Comment: The `print(__name__)` in `foo.py` is not executed twice because Python caches imported modules in `sys.modules` so they're only actually run once.

Comment: @martineau It's executed twice: once when `bar` executes `import foo`, and once after `import bar` completes in the script, since `foo.py` is used for `__main__` as well.

Comment: @chepner: Right…forgot that `foo.py` was being executed as `__main__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo.py` is executed twice, as its use as the main script is distinct from its use to define a module with the `import foo` statement in `bar.py`. (If it were *imported* multiple times, there would still only be two executions: one for the first time a module is needed, and once for its role as the main script.)

Once `import bar` has completed in `foo.py`, there are three entries in `sys.modules`:

1. One for the module `bar`
2. One for the module `foo`
3. One for the "special" module `__main__`

Each of the three modules has its own global variable `__name__`.

Comment: Hey, what will happen if I write ```import foo; print('Hello')``` in ```foo.py``` and run ```foo.py```? Will two modules be created this time? One ```__main__``` and other ```foo```? I executed this, but why ```Hello``` is printed twice instead of thrice?

Comment: The second time `import foo` is called, the contents of `foo.py` aren't executed, because the module `foo` was already created. That's what prevents you from an infinite cycle of importing and executing `foo`.

Comment: Can I say that ```foo``` was already present in ```sys.modules``` when I tried to *import foo* the second time and hence ```print('Hello')``` in the second module was directly executed?

Comment: Right. I think the way it works is that the module is created and inserted into `sys.modules` *before* the module is "populated", so that the chain of `import` statements is broken immediately.